# pandas plotting timespan aggregating a column

Tags: pandas, plot

I am attempting to plot data using a time span.
I am using pandas dataframes
The timespan is straight forward enough but
in all of the examples they generate data that fits into the times span.

How does one generate timespan plots that aggregate the data in a column to match the time frames ?

At the moment I am converting my index to timeseries and plotting the values to a column value as below

```
 series = pd.Series(df['value'], index=df.index)

 series.resample('12T',how='sum')

 series.plot()

  plt.show()
```

However the values which are 0 and 1 do not seem to get averaged and are either shooting from 0 to 1 or reverse in the graph rather than displaying an average over the time span specified

Comment: Please post an example.

Comment: Just solved it, I'll throw the answer was a doh moment

Answer (score 0):

Answer was stupidly easy.

I was plotting the series rather than the series with the frequency up dated as bellow

```
 series = pd.Series(df['value'], index=df.index)

  w = series.resample('1T',how='sum')


  w.plot()

  plt.show()
```